# Getting assertion error when trying to save a new field called location inside a post method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to save a field called location and pass it to data from the latitude and longitude like in this program. but getting an assertion error

```
AssertionError at /api/customer

When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.




    class CustomerView(APIView):           
        def get(self, request, format=None):
            query = CustomerProfile.objects.all()
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(query, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        
       def post(self, request, format=None):
           serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
           lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
           lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
           lat_1=float(lat)
           lon_1=float(lon)
           if serializer.is_valid():
              serializer.save(location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326))
              return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
           return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `serializer.is_valid()` or `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=true)` with exception, before accessing `serializer.data`

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
       serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=true)
       lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
       lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
       lat_1=float(lat)
       lon_1=float(lon)
       if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save(location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326))
          return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
       return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

Comment: Got this error
AttributeError at /api/customer
'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'location'

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this now. but getting
(1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'customer_customerprofile.user_id'") error. I know its because the saving is happening twice but no other method is working. So I decided to edit and save again with the instance. But I don't know how to use it in REST.

```
 def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
                lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
                lat_1=float(lat)
                lon_1=float(lon)
                location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326)
                id=serializer.data.get('user')
                v=CustomerProfile(location=location,user_id=id)
                v.save()
                return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
            return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, as mentionned, if you want to access the serializer data, you must first call `serializer.is_valid()`. Now I can see you added a new comment saying you've done this and you're getting a conflict/duplicate issue.

When calling `serializer.save()`, if you're using a `ModelSerializer`, this will either:

- CREATE a new instance for that model
- UPDATE the initially-given instance

So, looking at your code, it seems you're doing the job twice

```py
instance = serializer.save()  # <--- Creates/Updates and RETURNS the instance with the serializer data
# Could remove from here 
lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
lat_1=float(lat)
lon_1=float(lon)
location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326)
id=serializer.data.get('user')
v=CustomerProfile(location=location,user_id=id)
v.save()
# to there
return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
```

The job of the `ModelSerializer` is to create/update a model using the data given to that serializer, and return that created/updated instance

Now, if you wanted to make additional updates outside of your serializer, you could do something like that:

```py
# Creation example
serializer = MyModelSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
created_instance = serializer.save()
instance.some_field = True
instance.save()

# Update example
instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)  # Could use self.get_object() in a ModelViewSet
serializer = MyModelSerializer(instance, data=request.data)  # We passed the instance
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
updated_instance = serializer.save()
instance.some_field = True
instance.save()
```